# ReactJS: propTypes validation for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an array of objects

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      customtitle: '',
      IconSRC: '',
      btnColor: '',
      inlineSyle: '',
      btnStyle: {
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        flexDirection: 'column',

      },
      num: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      customtitle: '',
      IconSRC: '',
      btnColor: '',
      inlineSyle: '',
      btnStyle: {
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        flexDirection: 'column',

      },
      num: 2,
    },]
```

and i confused to making it work as props validation .I need help to fix it, I try this way

```
Function.propTypes = {
  list: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    btnColor: PropTypes.string,
    customTitle: PropTypes.string,
    btnStyle:PropTypes.object
    IconSRC: PropTypes.string,
    inlineSyle: PropTypes.string,
  })),
};
Function.defaultProps = {
  List: [],
};
```

But that didn't work. 
without this proptypes my component works correctly. but eslint show an error with this text

> .map' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is actually `PropTypes.arrayOf()`. For example:

```
list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    btnColor: PropTypes.string,
    customTitle: PropTypes.string,
    btnStyle:PropTypes.object
    IconSRC: PropTypes.string,
    inlineSyle: PropTypes.string,
  })),
```

You can see a full list of PropTypes [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Comment: `arrayOf` with a lowercase `a`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks. and another thing that PropTypes.object is forbidden.what should I use? defaultProps also have a problem with `List: []` it say >defaultProp "List" has no corresponding propTypes declaration

Comment: @zeiasoroush there's a typo, you have `list` in the `propTypes` but `List` in the `defaultProps`.

Comment: @zeiasoroush `PropTypes.object` is discouraged, but if you're not going to use it, you could just ignore it completely. Or, use `PropTypes.shape` again and define the `btnStyle` properties that you're going to use.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thank you for your fast answer.I understood the problem

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch. Yes, it is indeed `arrayOf` not `ArrayOf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like:

```
Function.propTypes = {
  list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    btnColor: PropTypes.string,
    customTitle: PropTypes.string,
    btnStyle:PropTypes.object
    IconSRC: PropTypes.string,
    inlineSyle: PropTypes.string,
  })),
};
Function.defaultProps = {
  List: [],
};
```

Also for more details about proptypes, visit Typechecking With PropTypes [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)